# Cambiar color barra de notificaciones android studio

Tags: android, layout, color

Quiero que dependiendo del activity la barra de notificaciones (Donde sale la bateria, señal, etc) cambie de color.

Por ejemplo, si estoy en Activity_main esta barra sea azul y si estoy en Activity_about sea de color naranjo.

En su defecto, ¿como puedo cambiar el hexadecimal en colors.xml mediante programación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo único que quieres es cambiar el color de la barra de notificaciones cuando cambies de actividad, solo tienes que aplicar un tema diferente en cada actividad, lo cual lo puedes hacer desde xml.

Lo primero es definir los temas que utilizaras en las actividades, pueden ser temas muy parecidos en los que solo cambies el color de la barra de notificaciones. La propiedad que modifica este color es `colorPrimaryDark`. Los temas se definen en el archivo **styles.xml**.

```
<!--Thema por defecto-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!--Tema de la SegundaActivity-->
<style name="ThemeSegundaActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item> <!--Color naranja-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Después en el **AndroidManifest.xml** a cada actividad le asignas un tema diferente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="davidminaya.respuestasstackoverflow">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Respuestas Stack Overflow"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SegundaActivity"
            <!--Con esta sentencia le asignas el tema a la actividad-->
            android:theme="@style/ThemeSegundaActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

En este caso el color de la barra de notificaciones en la SegundaActivity sera de color naranja.

> Ten en cuenta que si no le asignas un tema a la actividad, el tema por defecto de esta es el tema de la aplicación.

Comment: No sabia que se podía aplicar un tema para cada actividad, muchas gracias!

Comment: Pues claro amigo. Te recomiendo que te leas esta [guia oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html) de Android, donde se explica muy detalladamente como utilizar los temas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información lo andaba buscando.